# Restrict WordPress user to only edit posts with meta key value - WordPress admin

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress site set up, inside it, I have created Role SubAdmin.

For posts in the admin area, I have added a meta field called "content_author".

I have restricted the listing successfully in admin area using below filter

```
add_filter( 'parse_query', array( $this,"addPostsAdminFilter") );    

public function addPostsAdminFilter($query)
{
global $pagenow;
    $type = '';

    if (isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
        $post_type = $_GET['post_type'];
    }

    if ( $post_type == $type && $pagenow=='edit.php' && !is_super_admin())
    {
        if ( ! $query->get( 'meta_query' ) ) //lets set meta query to filter current users listing only
        {
            $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

            $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'content_author',
                    'value' => $current_user->ID,
                ),
            ));
        }
    } 
}
```

So it is limiting the list, But the problem comes here. When I have direct edit link available of any other post. I can open it easily and edit it. I don't want the user to have an access to other posts.

Can anyone help me?